# Serial port communication between Nodejs and Arduino

Tags: node.js, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to communication between Arduino and Nodejs. But problem is when I communicate between I got correct reading as well as some garbage reading in between correct reading. Still cant understand how to resolve this problem ?

**Here is the  Nodejs part which is used to read data  from COM port**

```
      var SerialPort = require("serialport").SerialPort;
      var serialport = new SerialPort("COM23",{baudrate:9600});
      serialport.on('open', function(){

           serialport.on('data', function(data){
           console.log(data[0]);
           });
      });
```

**Here is my simple Arduino code**

```
       int led = 13;
       void setup() {                
           Serial.begin(9600);
           pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
       }
       void loop() {

           digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
           Serial.write(1);
           delay(1000);  
           digitalWrite(led, LOW);
           Serial.write(0);
           delay(1000);               
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Limit the size of the data transferred, also define a parser for the serial transmission.

take a look to the serial port documentation https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport#parsers

You have two options "raw" and "readline".

> Out of the box, node-serialport provides two parsers one that simply emits the raw buffer as a data event and the other which provides familiar "readline" style parsing. To use the readline parser, you must provide a delimiter as such '\n'

here is an example for node.js.

```
   var sp = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.usbmodem14111', {
   //sp.parsers.readline('\r')
   //serialport.parsers.raw
       baudrate: 9600,
       parser: serialport.parsers.readline('\n')
   });
```

in the Arduino side, use the Serial function println();

```
    Serial.println("your message to the node server");
```

I hope this helps.